# delay between action and keystroke

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a macro for a video game. I want it to send a series of keyboard actions but also monitor the player's lifebar. My problem is when I use the hotkeys under #COMBOS: they are too laggy. Sometimes they'll register but not quickly. I assume it's because pyautogui is searching for the screenshot area within the loop. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def invis():
    keyboard.press_and_release("q")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("q")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("w")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("r")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("d")
def tornado():
    keyboard.press_and_release("w")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("w")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("q")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("r")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
    keyboard.press_and_release("d")

def Combos():
    while True:
            lasthit = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('lifebar.png', confidence=(0.80), grayscale=True)
            if lasthit:
                invis()
                time.sleep(35)
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
            #COMBOS:
            #Invis
            if keyboard.is_pressed('0'):
                invis()
            #Tornado
            if keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
                tornado()
```

Comment: A load of calls to `time.sleep` can't help... you're purposefully introducing lag/delay

Comment: Look again please. If the else: time.sleep(1) is removed it still acts the same. There is supposed to be a 0.1 - 0.3 second sleep between the keystrokes. That part works as it's supposed to. It's something to do with the     while True:
            lasthit = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('lifebar.png', confidence=(0.80), grayscale=True)
            if lasthit:
                invis()
                time.sleep(35)

Comment: you're purposefully introducing lag/delay – yes there is supposed to be delay between the keystrokes in the two functions on top. But that's not the issue. When I remove while True: lasthit = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('lifebar.png', confidence=(0.80), grayscale=True) if lasthit: invis() time.sleep(35) it works flawlessly and exectutes the keystrokes the way I want. But when I have the pyautogui.locateOnScreen section there is a big delay and sometimes it won't register a keystroke.